# Paypal IPN response $res is empty

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

this is the first time I am using Paypal to process a payment.  I have set up a developer account, created some test merchant/buyer accounts and successfully created a cart that I sent to paypal sandbox. Here, using one of my buyers accounts, I can, again, successfully complete the purchase. In the account history of paypal, it shows that the transaction was completed. All good till now.

The problem lays in the return url, where I get the IPN. Here is the code I copied from paypal website.

```
<?php

    include($_SERVER['WROOT'].'core/init.php');

    //Put together postback info

    $postback = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

    foreach($_POST as $key =>$value){
        $postback .= "&$key=$value";
    }

    // EMAIL $postback

    // build the header string to post back to PayPal system to validate
    $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $header .= "Host: www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($postback) . "\r\n\r\n";

    // also tried with $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
    $fp = fsockopen ('www.sandbox.paypal.com', 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);

    if(!$fp){ //no conn
        die();
    }

    //post data back
    fputs($fp, $header . $postback);

    while(!feof($fp)){

        $res=stream_get_contents($fp, 1024);

        if((strcmp($res, "VERIFIED")) == 0){
                    // EMAIL with a success notification 
            // update the database - THIS IS ONLY A SMALL TEST TO SEE IF THE TRANSACTION IS SUCCESSFUL -
            $new = $dbh->prepare(" ISNERT INTO orders(txn_id) VALUES(:txn_id) ");
            $new->execute(array( 'txn_id' => $_POST['txn_id'] ));

        } else if ( strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0 ) {
               // EMAIL with a error notification
               // LOG THE ERROR TO A FILE
            }
    }

?>
```

Ok, first of all I don't do any check to see if the email, gross amount and other parameters are valid, that is something I will do after I can solve this problem.

Anyway, after a buyer pays, my database should update, but it does not.

What I did ?

First of all, I email me the `$postback` variable as soon as it's created and it worked. I got the email with a huge string of response and all the data was correct.

But the `$res` variable is not either `VERIFIED` or `INVALID` so anything past the `fsockopen()` does not work.

As I said, the payment on the paypal website is successfull. The documentation is fairly poor and I can't get an answer.

The one thing I want to add is that my website does NOT have a SSL certificate, but I do not store any of the customer data, everything is processed on the secure paypal website. Do I need a SSL certificate ?

One last thing. I tried using this class https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN and the error log message is `Invalid response status: 302`

Comment: you just `die()` if the fsockopen fails, you need to check if there is an error message and display it or put in a log and see what it says.

Comment: Thanks, any advice what I should do in that case ? I just tried mail me an email instead of die() but the email is not arriving. Any help ?

Comment: If you're not receiving an email you might not have an outgoing mail server set up where you're running the code. You'll need to install one or just use another server's SMTP details. That, or just write the error message to a file (or store in a database) locally.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the problem here. Of course the mail works, AS I said already I recive the mail with the $postback variable

Comment: I'd recommend you using code from this page: [link](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_ipn.php) . As the code you are using from paypal documentation is kind of old.

Comment: @qwaz , your link is no longer valid.  The updated link is currently [here](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/blob/master/php/PaypalIPN.php) and requires the server have curl + ssl enabled.